# Are there any APIs in Appium for automating the bluetooth functionality of Android and iOS?

Tags: bluetooth, appium

Are there any APIs in Appium for automating the bluetooth functionality of Android and iOS?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. I'm afraid this question is unlikely to be well received by the community here because it is too broad and also doesn't sound as if you have done any research. You would be best reading the documentation; if you then have a go, and you get stuck, that is the time to post a question here (including your code, what you expect to happen, what actually happens, and any error messages).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking for library recommendations is considered [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here, as it attracts too many opinion-based answers and information which is already easily found online.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer some test written by Appium java client [here](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/7cbdcd4b9ee53389c7ffa71e584adcb8118ef70d/src/test/java/io/appium/java_client/android/AndroidConnectionTest.java) for creating connections